# How to fix "error path not found" in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build an API of my blogging website using Django rest framework, but my URL is not matching.

I am trying Django Rest framework for the first time so I am not quite able to fix this. But I think I mess this up in url_patterns.

Here is my URL code from the main directory(the directory which contains settings.py) .
`

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from blog import views

from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'apipost',views.PostViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'',include('blog.urls')),
    path('api-auth/',include('rest_framework.urls',namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

`

I am trying url http://127.0.0.1:8000/apipost and expect to get value in json format.

Comment: use `/` after the url

Comment: @ShafikurRahman I tried this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/apipost/` but still got this error `The current path, apipost/, didn't match any of these.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `router.urls` to your `urlpatterns`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'',include('blog.urls')),
    path('api-auth/',include('rest_framework.urls',namespace='rest_framework')),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Comment: Thanks, it shows login page but according to the official tutorial it should work without routers.[Django Rest Framework Tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#adding-login-to-the-browsable-api) . But it shows no page found.

Answer (score 0):

Django REST Framework Won't magically register your router in urlpatterns, you have to do it by yourself. You can use `urlpatterns += router.urls` if you want to add them to the root of your urlpatterns, or `url(r'^api/', include((router.urls, 'app_name'))),` if you want to set subpath for them.